# Ejabberd archive table MySQL partitioning

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

I have Ejabberd with MySQL DB Type. My Archive Table is growing it more than 10GB now so I want to Partition the Archive Table to have fast performance.

What is the Partitioning Option I shall Use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about MySQL, so I point to an alternative solution: if those MAM archived messages are useless after some time, you can delete old ones with https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#delete-old-mam-messages

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But i need to maintain some large number of messages.